# How to format floppy disks in a USB floppy disk drive on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, usb-drive, scsi, floppy

I want to format a MF 2HD floppy in a USB floppy disk drive.  Since a USB floppy disk drive appears as a da(4) device instead of an fdc(4) device, the standard `fdformat` utility cannot be used.  How can I format my floppy disk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As no formatting program seems to exist, I wrote the following shell script which sends appropriate FORMAT UNIT commands to format all 80 tracks of a floppy disk.  The device `da0` is formatted unless a different device is supplied as an argument.  The CDB has been taken from the [UFI specification](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/usbmass-ufi10.pdf).

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e
exec >&2

drive=${1:-da0}
numblocks=2880
blocklen=512
tracks=80
track=0

progress() {
    [ -t 2 ] && printf "\\r%2d/%2d" $track $tracks
}


for track in `seq 0 $((tracks-1))`
do
    progress

    # format bottom
    camcontrol cmd "$drive" -v \
        -c '04 17 i1 00 00 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00' $track \
        -o 12 '00 b0 00 08 i4 00 i3' $numblocks $blocklen

    # format top
    camcontrol cmd "$drive" -v \
        -c '04 17 i1 00 00 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00' $track \
        -o 12 '00 b1 00 08 i4 00 i3' $numblocks $blocklen

done

track=$tracks
progress
[ -t 2 ] && echo
```